# IL / CLR / DLR References?

Tags: .net, clr, dynamic-language-runtime, il

I'm wanting to learn more about IL and CLR / DLR under the hood.  A friend of mine recommended the book "Inside Microsoft .NET IL Assembler", but since it came out in 2002 I fear it's pretty out of date at this point.

Does anyone have any more up-to-date books or websites that can be used by someone who understands .NET languages to learn more about the inner workings of IL and the CLR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps my answer is a bit late now, but the book "MS Press - Inside Microsoft .NET IL Assembler" is actually excellent.
Remember: framework 3.X only adds new classes and functionality. Underlying technology is still the same. So the book still stands, at least until FW3.5.

Side to side to ECMA, and some hard work, you have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

For an interesting look at CLR low-level details I like SSCLI Essentials.  Not so useful for IL / DLR.

Answer (score 2):

The [ECMA 335 CLI standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) is good reading.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you check out some of the more detailed chapters in CLR Via C# by Jeffrey Richter.  It doesn't go into as much detail as you'd like probably, but its a good start and covers the 2.0 CLR and so is somewhat current through .NET 4.0.

Comment: CLR Via C# is an excellent place to get started - it's taught me more about the inner workings of the CLR than any other book, highly recommended!

Comment: A 3rd edition, [including 4.0 content](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2009/06/17/clr-via-c-3rd-edition.aspx) (which I assume includes the DLR) is in the planning stages; not sure where it stands at this moment, however.